# OneDrive says "test copy link local document" when I try to share the link

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-onedrive

I am trying to share a link to a OneDrive document.

I click "share" then "copy link".
[image: Word Share -> Copy Link]

but I get this odd message.
[image: OneDrive sharing test copy link local document]

Usually, it would say something like "link copied" but this doesn't copy the link.  When I paste it is whatever I copied previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this bug today too.

It's because the file has not yet finished saving to OneDrive.

If you look at the title bar, you'll notice it says "Saving..." - if you let it finish saving, it'll work as expected.

If it's stuck on "Saving..." you have to quit Word and reopen the file.

Comment: Ah ha, got it, thanks for taking the time to write a response.  Welcome to SuperUser :)